# google-cloud-storage random 503 error in PATCH

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have a code that reads files from a bucket then edit the content_encoding from all files metadata. It usually works fine, but since 3 days ago i'm heaving problems with the google-cloud-storage API, it seems to be returning 503 errors randomly. I already tried to use a retry strategy with an 600 seconds deadline but the code still returning errors.

Im running this code with python3 in a databricks notebook with an 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12) cluster.

google-cloud-srtorage API version -> 2.5.0

I read some old threads about this problem, and it seems to be a known issue but im still not able to resolve it. Here is the code:

```
def blob_list(bucket_name):
  try:
    client = storage.Client()
    blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    print('Bucket read')
    return blobs
  except Exception as e:
    print('Counld not read the bucket', e)
    
b = blob_list(bucket_name)
count = 0
modified_retry = DEFAULT_RETRY.with_deadline(600)
modified_retry = modified_retry.with_delay(initial=1.5, multiplier=1.2, maximum=45.0)

for item in b:
  CS = storage.Client()
  blob = CS.bucket(bucket_name).blob(item.name)
  blob.patch(retry=modified_retry)
#  print(blob.content_encoding)
  if blob.content_encoding == 'gzip' or blob.content_encoding == 'txt': 
    blob.content_encoding = 'csv'
    blob.patch(retry=modified_retry)
    count +=1
print('Changed',count,'metadata files')
```

The code is taking too long to run and still throwing This error

Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: 503 PATCH https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/yof0soyd7668_2022-08-15T060000_06db87dcb5e5ee06ec13ab5fbefe4df0_be822a.csv.gz?projection=full&prettyPrint=false: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.

The error seems to occurs in the patch() method.

Comment: Are you running this code in Cloud Functions? Edit your question with details.

Comment: I'd also suggest running the app with Python client debug on and update the question with the underlying API call details ... see:

https://medium.com/@franknatividad/debug-cloud-storage-client-libraries-f50f46ce7f6

Comment: Where are you finding that blob.content_encoding has an allowed value of 'csv'?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with the PATCH method with a MIME type of `text/csv`

Comment: And my code is running in a Cloud Composer v2 environment on a GKE Autopilot cluster underneath. The code has not been changed in 15 months.

Comment: `pip install google-cloud-storage = "==1.36.1"`

`blob = self.get_blob(bucket=$BUCKET, blob_name=$BLOB_NAME)`

`blob.patch()`
-> 503

Comment: Im running this code with python3 in a databricks notebook.

Comment: @Kolban I didn't find it anywhere, but as the files are uploaded from a external source to this bucket with gzip in the content encoding, i tried to change to csv and then read into a dataframe. And it worked, so i assume that i was fine.

Comment: @Matheus ... I don't consider myself any kind of an expert in this area but my line of thinking is that there is a distinction between "content type" and "content encoding".  I am thinking content type is the "format" of the data ... such as CSV, JSON, HTML, TEXT etc ... while content encoding is how is this textual data "stored" or "encoded".  Compression such as through "gzip" indicates (to me) that it is compressed .. but that doesn't change the encoding.  Maybe it isn't encoding you want to change but content type?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately an issue on Google's end.  I am getting the same 503 error as you on processes that I have been running daily for over 2 years.  I created a support case through GCP and am waiting to hear back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If its not too much to ask, let us know when you have an answer from them.

Comment: I received the following from them this afternoon -

"According to the Cloud Storage API specialist team update, we are doing some roll back activity to fix this error.  Therefore this activity takes some more time to finish.  I will get back to you with an update on or before 8 PM PDT 27th August 2022"

Comment: Google got back to me and said they completed the roll back.  I tested on my end late afternoon and the patch no longer returns a 503 error.  Hope the same is the case for you.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, it no longer returns 503 for me too.

Comment: I observe again `503 PATCH https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/... We encountered an internal error. Please try again` from GCP Storage API.